# Order WordPress meta_key

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to order a WordPress query by the meta_key (evento_fecha) but it's ordering by Add/Edit time.

evento_fecha is a custom meta box (jquery date picker), stored like (2017-03-04)

Take a look to my code:

```php
<?php 
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$args_eventos = array(
            'post_type'    => 'eventos',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'meta_key'     => 'evento_fecha',
            'meta_value'   => date( "Y-m-d" ),
            'meta_compare' => '>=',
);

$query_eventos = new WP_Query( $args_eventos );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this query

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");    
$args_eventos = array(
        'post_type'  => 'eventos',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'evento_fecha',
                'value'   =>  date( "Y-m-d" ),
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query_eventos = new WP_Query( $args_eventos );
```

Take a reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks! @rafin-karki I get the right order adding: 'orderby' =>'meta_value_num' and 'meta_key' => 'evento_fecha'.

Answer (score 0):

I get the right order using this:

> ```
> 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
> 'meta_key' => 'evento_fecha',
> ```

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$args_eventos = array(
        'post_type'    => 'eventos',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'meta_key'     => 'evento_fecha',
        'meta_value'   => date( "Y-m-d" ),
        'meta_compare' => '>=',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'evento_fecha',
    );

$query_eventos = new WP_Query( $args_eventos ); ?>
```